# Bootstrap Tooltip - Weird box around popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

[image: Display of ToolTip Issue]

I've never seen this issue before, but can't seem to find where it's coming from.. has anyone seen this or what could be causing it? I haven't adjusted any tooltip css

Comment: Please look with an inspector of the browser where these styles are coming from. Maybe you have additional styles declared somewhere...

Comment: I tried using the inspect - it doesn't show it. It's quite odd - and can't be found anywhere online

Comment: What browser? Have you tried another browser? Any weird extensions installed? Could you share a picture of the inspector output. What styles are applied to the tooltip and and the divs around or in it

Comment: Yup, tried all browsers. No extensions. The inspector is a challenge because I can't select the tooltip.. just the div's and elements around it. Unless you know how I can? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You could manipulate the classes in your inspector that the tooltip will always show. Or right click on the element which triggers the tooltip and choose "set state > active" or hover.  That should make the tooltip always visible and then you are able to inspect the styles.

Alternative: look at the bootstrap docs how to create a tooltip which is always visible

Comment: add your code like jsfiddle